# Why won't my C# Recursion stop when it hits true?

Tags: c#, recursion, visual-studio-2017

I tried to make a function that finds the fastest route to the end of the array by making a recursion that chooses its path by first availability. for some reason, the recursion doesn't stop when it returns true. why?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] arr = new int[5, 5];
        arr[0, 0] = 2;
        if (PathFinder(arr, 0, 0))
        { 
        printarr(arr);
        }
    }

    static bool PathFinder(int[,] arr, int y,int x)
    {


        if (arr[arr.GetLength(0) - 1, arr.GetLength(1) - 1] == 2)
        {   
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            /////Right
            if (x != arr.GetLength(1) - 1 && arr[y, x + 1] != 2 && arr[y, x + 1] == 0)
            {
                arr[y, x + 1] = 2;
                printarr(arr);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                PathFinder(arr, y, x + 1);

            }
            /////Down
            if (y != arr.GetLength(0) - 1 && arr[y + 1, x] != 2 && arr[y + 1, x] == 0)
            {
                arr[y + 1, x] = 2;
                printarr(arr);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                PathFinder(arr, y + 1, x);

            }
            /////UP
            if (y!=0 && arr[y-1,x]!=2 && arr[y - 1, x] == 0)
            {
                arr[y - 1, x] = 2;
                printarr(arr);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                PathFinder(arr,y-1,x);

            }
            /////Left
            if (x != 0 && arr[y, x-1] != 2 && arr[y, x - 1] == 0)
            {
                arr[y, x - 1] = 2;
                printarr(arr);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                PathFinder(arr, y, x - 1);

            }
            return false;

        }


    }

    static void printarr(int[,] arr)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int colom = 0; colom < arr.GetLength(1); colom++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[row, colom] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does debugging says?

Comment: I suspect your lines that look like `PathFinder(arr, y, x - 1);` should look like `return PathFinder(arr, y, x - 1);` (as an example).

Comment: thanks man that fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a method that has a return type recursively without storing that return value, it will proceed after the call. You have called it by name `PathFinder(...` so when true is returned your recursive call doesn't pass it on. Change your code like this:

```
static bool PathFinder(int[,] arr, int y, int x)
{
    if (arr[arr.GetLength(0) - 1, arr.GetLength(1) - 1] == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        /////Right
        if (x != arr.GetLength(1) - 1 && arr[y, x + 1] != 2 && arr[y, x + 1] == 0)
        {
            arr[y, x + 1] = 2;
            printarr(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return PathFinder(arr, y, x + 1);
        }
        /////Down
        if (y != arr.GetLength(0) - 1 && arr[y + 1, x] != 2 && arr[y + 1, x] == 0)
        {
            arr[y + 1, x] = 2;
            printarr(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return PathFinder(arr, y + 1, x);
        }
        /////UP
        if (y != 0 && arr[y - 1, x] != 2 && arr[y - 1, x] == 0)
        {
            arr[y - 1, x] = 2;
            printarr(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return PathFinder(arr, y - 1, x);
        }
        /////Left
        if (x != 0 && arr[y, x - 1] != 2 && arr[y, x - 1] == 0)
        {
            arr[y, x - 1] = 2;
            printarr(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return PathFinder(arr, y, x - 1);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way, when you hit `return true;`, that value will be passed along all the way back the call stack and you won't continue processing until your return false;

Recursive calls to methods without a return type should have a `return;` statement somewhere so they can escape otherwise you'll hit a `StackOverflowException`.